# StreamWriter how to get to ignore \r\n?

Tags: excel, io, newline, streamwriter

I am building "export" functionality; I am using a StreamWriter to write some data in CSV format so that it can be opened in excel.

Problem is, it turns out that in that data, there is the string `\r\n` which seems to be causing the StreamWriter to treat this as newline, and this stuffs up the table in excel.

Is there a way to ignore the `\r\n` ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the .Replace("\r\n", ""); 
also to make the answer more exact could you paste the code where you are parsing and or creating the comma delimited file ..?

Comment: This is how I ended up solving it but I don't believe it is a proper solution because I have modified the data. I should be able to have \r\n as it is in the database, in my excel export. I tried `Html.Encode()` still no luck. There should be a way to tell the StreamWriter to ignore the escape sequence, or encode it, or something...

Comment: I have never had the problem that you are experiencing but once again it's hard to tell what additional issues you are experiencing without at least seeing a screen shot or same of the data that you are trying to read in..